# Find Min, Max and Average of two fields in dictionary

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

After process the data, I have a batch of rows with the format

```
(u'378491520468_sale', {'price': 2100000, 'built': 3815})

(u'378491119.1537520468_sale', {'price': 2100000, 'built': 3815})

(u'1306084076.1535728358_rent', {'price': 1400, 'built': 1109})

(u'1303342766.1548320090_sale', {'price': 550, 'built': 1200})

(u'1890530682.1515660872_sale', {'price': 130000, 'built': 759})

(u'8212134.1548317851_rent', {'price': 2900, 'built': 1220})

(u'1170655463.1513653914_sale', {'price': 430000, 'built': 1142})

(u'58676746.1548308550_sale', {'price': 1700000, 'built': 3000})

(u'1162578480.1474216313_sale', {'price': 10000000, 'built': 3})

(u'1860145003.1546594155_rent', {'price': 4200, 'built': 839})

(u'1640943061.1489124089_sale', {'price': 710000, 'built': 1600})

(u'1008351255.1547539066_rent', {'price': 15000, 'built': 8400})

(u'903442891.1547795833_sale', {'price': 148000, 'built': 786})
```

where the first element in the set is the unique ID.

I know about the basic combineFn class that able to group (key, value) and count the min, max and average in a fixed window. But with a dictionary as value, I need some guidance to compute them with a format of:

```
("the_unique_id", {
            "price":{
                "min": 0,
                "max": 0,
                "average": 0
            },
            "built": {
                "min": 0,
                "max": 0,
                "average": 0
            }
        ), ...
```

Comment: What `min`, `max`, and `average` represent in your case??

Comment: For a fixed window of data, it will be the minimum, maximum and average price for the particular key. For example, unique key of abc with price of 1,2,3 within the windowing time will produce min = 1, max = 3 and average = 2. Same goes to built.

Comment: But, the price you have provided is just a one number.. right??

Comment: I am stating only one example. You can assume they come in batches:

(u'378491520468_sale', {'price': 2100000, 'built': 3815})
(u'378491520468_sale', {'price': 2120000, 'built': 3815})
(u'378491512468_sale', {'price': 1010000, 'built': 2524})
(u'378491512468_sale', {'price': 1100000, 'built': 2521})

Comment: What format is your data in? Is it a Pandas DataFrame, a list of tuples, rows from a sqlite database etc.

Comment: It is from PubSub streaming. I will define a windowing function to take a group of them and perform the calculation

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the data into the form below, here is a way to calculate the aggregate values:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'ID': [u'378491520468_sale', u'378491119.1537520468_sale', u'1306084076.1535728358_rent'],
        'price': [2100000, 2100000, 1400],
        'built': [3815, 3815, 1109]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

aggregates = {
    'price': ['min', 'max', 'mean'],
    'built': ['min', 'max', 'mean'],
}

df = df.groupby('ID').agg(aggregates)

res = []

for i in range(len(df)):
    row = df.iloc[i]
    res.append((row.name,
                {'price': {'min': row['price']['min'],
                           'max': row['price']['max'],
                           'average': row['price']['mean']},
                 'built': {'min': row['built']['min'],
                           'max': row['built']['max'],
                           'average': row['built']['mean']}}))

print(res)
```

Comment: I am grateful for your solution but I am developing the code in Apache Beam, https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/

Comment: @MervynLee Ah, I see. Sorry, got confused by the Python tag. I'll leave this up here in case someone else has a similar problem in Python.